# Clipping Space In OpenGL Pipeline

Tags: opengl, graphics, matrix, pipeline, clipping

How does clipping and projecting work in a simplified explanation? It has something to do with normalizing the vertices and matrix multiplication that involves dividing x,y,z by a 4th variable. I am having trouble understanding what actually happens.

Comment: No "simplified explanation" can do the subject justice; either it is properly explained or it isn't. [My explanation for the concept](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut04%20Perspective%20Projection.html) is suitably long and comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks I will read through it.

Answer (score 5):

Its pretty simple.
Clipping is process that says if primitive (point, line or triangle) is visible. (and is done after modelview* projection matrix transformation) if triangle is partially visible, triangle is split into more triangles that fit in frustum.

After clipping is done, we need to normalize **vertex** (*x,y,z,w*) coordinates in order to project them to screen (window coordinates). This is called perspective division: new coordinates is `x,y,z,1 = x/w, y/w, z/w, 1`. Windows coordinates are dependant on viewport settings, and transformation is very simple.

```
window_x = viewport_x + vertex_x * half_viewport_width + half_viewport_width;
window_y = viewport_y + vertex_y * half_viewport_height + half_viewport_height;
```